# Why does this TVF throw error 9820 with GETDATE() as an input parameter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, table-valued-parameters

I am testing on SQL Server 2019 CU14. Consider the following table-valued function created against a SQL Server database with compatibility level 130 or 140:

```
-- requires database compat 130 or 140 to see the issue
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TVF_BUG_REPRO_2] (@O DateTime, @Z varchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
SELECT
CAST(
       CASE
              WHEN SZ.Zone1 > '' THEN (@O at time zone SZ.Zone1) at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time' 
              WHEN LEN(@Z) > 3 THEN (@O at time zone @Z) at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time'
              ELSE @O
       END AS DATETIME
) ConvertedDate
FROM (SELECT CASE @Z WHEN 'ET' THEN 'Eastern Standard Time' ELSE NULL END Zone1) SZ;
```

The following query executes without error and returns the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TVF_BUG_REPRO_2] ('2022-01-10 16:16:51.327', 'ET');
```

The following query unexpectedly throws an error:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TVF_BUG_REPRO_2] (GETDATE(), 'ET');
```

The error message is:

> Msg 9820, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
>
> The time zone parameter 'ET' provided to AT TIME ZONE clause is invalid.

I don't understand why I'm getting an error here. That code should never execute. Running the code without a function as a simple `SELECT` also does not throw any errors.

Why does that query fail? Could this be a bug in SQL Server?

Comment: Call stack of error is https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBaGE.png. `CQueryExecContext::FillExprCache` is mentioned here https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html - so it is trying to evaluate and cache the value at runtime rather than compile time but before the query execution "proper" begins. Maybe related to runtime constant nature of `getdate()`?

Comment: It appears this is fixed in SQL Server 2019 CU16 and SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, a function of this form works:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TVF_BUG_REPRO_2] (@O DateTime, @Z varchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
SELECT
CAST(@O at time zone SZ.Zone at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time' AS DATETIME ) ConvertedDate
FROM (SELECT CASE @Z WHEN 'ET' THEN 'Eastern Standard Time' ELSE @Z END Zone) SZ;
```

Answer (score -2):

in my case the time zone value was empty therefore, SQL was returning 9820 Error while getting UTC date/time value. Make sure in the above script @Z value ensure valid and not empty. for valid value [click here](https://database.guide/get-a-list-of-supported-time-zones-in-sql-server-t-sql/).

Comment: This is not a general question about any random case where the 9820 error appears. It is asking about why it incorrectly appears in a specific case